# implements Runnable - ONLY ONE method?

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable

I have a class with several methods (`casa()`, `run()`, `predio()`, ...). My class implements `Runnable`. When I create a thread with an object of my class, will it execute all the methods? Is there a ways to choose which one to execute? Here is my `Runnable` class:

```
public class acao implements Runnable {

    public void casa() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 90000; i++) {
            System.out.println(i + "casa");
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 90000; i++) {
            System.out.println("t" + i);
        }
    }

    public void predio() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 90000; i++) {
            System.out.println(i + "predio");
        }
    }

    public void carro() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 90000; i++) {
            System.out.println(i + "Carro");
        }
    }

}
```

And here is how I create a thread with it:

```
acao acao = new acao();
Thread threadDaAcao = new Thread(acao);
threadDaAcao.start();
```

Comment: What's Execultar/execultará ?

Comment: You are also new to Stackoverflow. So please spend some time on the help center in order to understand what makes up good questions ... in other words: no idea what you are asking for; please step back and keep in mind that WE are not YOU; we have no clue what you have on your mind.

Comment: Expensive? Has this been translated by google or bing somehow? If you are using Swing and JProgressBar, there are [examples on the Internet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html).

Comment: Sorry.   Will the "implement runnable" execute all methods? Is there a way to execute only a chosen one?

Comment: Are these 3 methods static? If not, do you always want them to be executed for the same instance of your class? Please include some code that would demonstrate what you are trying to do.

Comment: When you create a `Thread t = new Thread(r);` and then you call `t.start();` the new thread will call `r.run()` exactly one time, and then when the run method either returns or throws an exception, the thread will die.  If you want it to run other methods of the same class, you can call them from the run() method.  If you want it to run them all, then write your run() method to run them all.  If you want it to choose one, then write your run() method to do that instead.  You can put whatever you want in the run() method.

Comment: I want to use in a button , for example : casa() and predio( ) and other button predio() and car( ) . The Problem is that they are in the same class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it will not run all the methods, just the run() method. Read the javadoc of the java.lang.Thread class. It's also good practice to start classnames with a capital letter - so Acao, not acao.

In fact don't even need to make your own class Runnable. Use anonymous classes like this:

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Acao a = new Acao();
            a.predio();
            a.casa();
            a.carro();
        }
    });
t.start();
```

Comment: the idea is to use one or two of these method . Not all

Comment: Then you need to figure out how the thread should know which methods to call. You can store instance attributes in the Acao class to say "callMethodX"

Answer (score -1):

I had an ideia.

```
public class EscolheAcao implements Runnable {

public String acao;

public EscolheAcao(String a) {
    this.acao = a;
}

public void run() {
    escolhe(acao);
}

public void escolhe(String acao) {
    acao a = new acao();

    if (acao.equals("carro")) {
        a.carro();
    }
    if (acao.equals("casa")) {
        a.casa();
    }
    if (acao.equals("predio")) {
        a.predio();
    }
   }
}
```